# How to share easily files between Mac OS X and Windows 10

Tags: windows, macos, project, user-experience

I am asking if anyone of you know the best solution for this case:

This semester I have to make a project with an eye tracker (Tobii Eyex), but the problem with the hardware is that it is only compatible with Windows. So my question is: Is it possible to code on Mac and then get the stuff with ease on Windows, but only in a few seconds?

I tried it with file sharing, but the problem is that I can't keep two Unity instances running on the same project. 
The perfect solution would be, if I have made any changes, the Windows PC should automatically update the files.

Comment: Are you talking about coding on Mac and deploying to Windows, or are you talking about setting up a system where a Mac box and a Windows box are working together in some sort of automated synergy? If the first, source control is what you want.

Comment: Consider whacking it all on Dropbox.

Comment: I want to code on Mac and then deploy it on Window. Yeah, Github is probably the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Github](http://www.github.com/). It will allow you to keep your entire project synced across all devices with minimal effort.